# Can I use React-Router to render a component within an opened modal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router, reactstrap

I am trying to build a log in/sign up interface using Reactstrap (React components for Bootstrap v4) and React-Router. I have the sign in and sign up buttons available on a modal.

Once a user clicks either "sign in" or "sign up", I would like that button component within the modal to be swapped out for an input component so that the user can enter their information. I am trying to do this using React-Router, so that the component can be switched out within the modal without having to go to a new page or open a new modal.

Is something like this feasible? The modal currently does not open a new url, it simply appears over the existing page. 
I have included my code below:

**Modal Template**

```
 <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle} className={this.props.className}>
               <ModalHeader className="text-center">Get Started</ModalHeader>
               <ModalBody id="ModalBody">
                 <Row id="LoginRow">
                     <Router>
                       <Switch>
                         <Route exact path="/" component={SignUpSignIn} />
                         <Route exact path="/SignUp" component={SignIn} />
                         <Route exact path="/SignIn" component={SignUp} />
                       </Switch>
                     </Router>
                  </Row>
               </ModalBody>
             </Modal>
```

**Base Sign Up / Sign In Component**

```
    export default class SignUpSignIn extends Component {
      render () {
        return (
        <div id="SignUpSignInDiv">
          <Col md="12" sm="12" xs="12" className="text-center">
            <Button id="SignUpButton" color="primary" href="/SignUp" onClick={this.toggle}>Sign Up</Button>
           </Col>
           <Col md="12" sm="12" xs="12" className="text-center">
             <Button id="SignInButton" color="primary" href="/SignIn" onClick={this.toggle}>Sign In</Button>
            </Col>
        </div>
        )
      }
}
```

**Sign Up Component**

```
    export default class SignUp extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
    <div>
      <Col md="12" sm="12" xs="12" className="text-center">
        <Form />
       </Col>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Sign In Component**

```
export default class SignIn extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
    <div>
      <Col md="12" sm="12" xs="12" className="text-center">
        <Form />
       </Col>
    </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: did you try it and it didnt work ? because as far as i see your code seems correct

Comment: is there any reason you want do this with `react-router`? Something like this could be easily achieved with some component state that is set when either button is clicked

Comment: It is faster and easier to do with the component state. Have the click's change the state which runs a switch statement to output your visuals.